# As of macOS Big Sur, how do you see generator used by Quick Look?

Tags: command-line, quicklook, quicklook-plugin

Before macOS Big Sur, `qlmanage -p` by itself or `qlmanage -p -d debugLevel` showed which Quick Look generator was used for a given file. Now, no such info appears.

The man page for `qlmanage` also changed from

> qlmanage -p [-d debugLevel] [-x] [-c contentTypeUTI [-g generator]] [file ...]

to

> qlmanage -p [-x] [-c contentTypeUTI [-g generator]] [file ...]

**How can I, as of macOS Big Sur, see what Quick Look generator is used for a given file?**

Answer (score 1):

Try `qlmanage -m plugins`. That shows the list of generators for Uniform Type Indicators types, though I'll agree the difference in wording is odd (plugins / generators).

eg.

```
% qlmanage -m plugins
plugins:
  org.videolan.avi -> /Library/QuickLook/Video.qlgenerator (1.9.4)
  org.perian.nuppelvideo -> /Library/QuickLook/Video.qlgenerator (1.9.4)
  com.apple.iwork.keynote.sffkth -> /System/Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator (225)
  com.bittorrent.torrent -> /Applications/Transmission.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/QuickLookPlugin.qlgenerator (1.0)
  com.seriflabs.affinity -> /Applications/Affinity Photo.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/QuickLook.qlgenerator (5.1)
  com.microsoft.powerpoint.pot -> /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator (46)
  org.videolan.wmv -> /Library/QuickLook/Video.qlgenerator (1.9.4)
  org.perian.ogv -> /Library/QuickLook/Video.qlgenerator (1.9.4)
  com.adriangranados.wifiexplorer.document -> /Applications/WiFi Explorer.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/WiFiExplorer.qlgenerator (51)
  org.videolan.ogg-video -> /Library/QuickLook/Video.qlgenerator (1.9.4)
.
.
etc...
```

Comment: The list does not seem complete. For example, [QLMarkdown](https://github.com/sbarex/QLMarkdown) is active via /Applications/QLMarkdown.app, however does not show up in the list. In the old qlmanage, you could see which generator handled a specific file.

Comment: QLMarkdown is installed as an extension (see System Preferences | Extensions). I'm not sure how that differs from a QL generator in it's execution by Quicklook though...

Comment: I appreciate the pointer. It seems there are `.appex`-bundles (called _App Extensions_) and `.qlgenerator`-bundles (called _Quick Look Generators_). Both seem to achieve the same, namely show previews. Some apps have both, some have only one of them. — It seems `qlmanage -m` only shows the latter. I feel confused upon receiving this information.

Comment: `pluginkit -mvp com.apple.quicklook.preview QLSupportedContentTypes` show you relevant .appex bundles. To inquire into the content types, add the `--raw` flag in front and search for the `QLSupportedContentTypes` key.

Comment: Nice find. And it shows your missing QLMarkdown. Now you can provide another answer to your own question ;-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the command shows Uniform Type Indicators, not MIME types (which are usually in the style `application/pdf`)

Comment: @ma1234 Thx.. yeah I was probably generalising. Amended.